# What happens when I call .by_ref().take().rev() on a IntoIter

Tags: rust, iterator

Let's say I have a IntoIter and I want to collect chunks of n elements from right to left (equivalent to rchunks on slices). I can `.rev()` on the iterator and then call `.by_ref().take(n).rev()` for each chunk I want to collect.

```rust
let mut iter = vec![vec![0], vec![1], vec![2], vec![3]]
    .into_iter()
    .rev();

let vec1: Vec<_> = iter.by_ref().take(2).rev().collect();
println!("{:?}", vec1);

let vec2: Vec<_> = iter.by_ref().take(2).rev().collect();
println!("{:?}", vec2);
```

This works for `vec1` but `vec2` will be empty.

I was expecting `vec2` to be [[0], [1]] instead of empty. It seems like the `.rev()` method changes not only the Take iterator but the original one. Is it consuming the original iterator or what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, like many others, are misunderstanding how `take`, `rev` and the other iterator adapters work. They don't take/reverse/... directly, instead they wrap the underlying iterator and return a new one that behave as if it's only 2 long / iterated from the other end / ... so a `.rev() … chain of adapters … .rev()`ed iterator is iterated from the left, and so an adapter chain of `.rev().take(n).rev()` does traverse *all* elements and keeps only the last `n`, because the last `rev()` translates the `next()` calls to [`next_back()` of the `DoubleEndedIterator` implementation of `Take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/take.rs.html#154-162)
which skips to the first taken element with

```
self.iter.nth_back(self.iter.len().saturating_sub(n))
```

To achieve your desired effect, you have to `collect()` *before* you reverse the iterator again:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut iter = vec![vec![0], vec![1], vec![2], vec![3]].into_iter().rev();

    let vec1 = {
        let mut r = Vec::from_iter(iter.by_ref().take(2));
        r.reverse();
        r
    };
    println!("{:?}", vec1);

    let vec2 = {
        let mut r = Vec::from_iter(iter.by_ref().take(2));
        r.reverse();
        r
    };
    println!("{:?}", vec2);
}
```

Comment: This is further evidenced by the fact that you can only call `rev` on a `DoubleEndedIterator` - if the iterator does not know how to iterate from the end, you can't call that.

Comment: "instead they modify the underlying iterator to behave as if it's only 2 long / iterated from the other end" I don't know if I'm misunderstanding what you mean, but as far as I can tell that's not true? `Rev` does not modify the underlying iterator,what it does is call the underlying operator's `next_back` when you call `next` on it. Similarly `take` does not touch the underlying iterator, it just has a counter / limit, and pulls and returns an element from the underlying iterator when asked for one until the counter locks at 0.

Comment: Yep, that's not quite right, I've reworded it, does the new wording better fit with your understanding @Masklinn

Comment: Taking a stab at a complement as it took me a minute to grok the way `take().rev()` works (which is not intuitive but is logical): Rust has no concept of random access iterators, so all `Take` knows is that the iterator it wraps can be iterated from the back (and has a fixed size). So when `Rev` calls `next_back()` on `Take`, in order to get its last element `Take` has to consume (skip) the entire tail of the iterator it wraps. Which because it wraps a `rev` irrecoverably advances the underlying iterator.

Comment: So the first `rev()` just signals that the iteration will be from the back. Then `take(n)` signals the calling of `next_back()` n times. And then another `rev()` signals that the iteration will actually use `next()` but only on the indices that would be returned by `.rev().take(n)`, so the underlying iterator is consumed. Is this correct?

Comment: They're not signals. [`Rev::next()` literally calls `self.iter.next_back()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/rev.rs.html#33-35). That is [`Take::next_back()` which calls `self.iter.nth_back(self.n)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/take.rs.html#154-162). That is [`Rev::nth_back` which calls `self.iter.nth()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/rev.rs.html#92-94). Which is [`Iterator::nth`, which advances the iterator and discards the items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#395-398).